# How do I get comment count of each blog post in ListView via Get_context_data? Filtering by self.id/self.object.id/self does not work

Tags: django, django-views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

from journal.models import Post, Corrections, Comments

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['comment_count'] = Comments.objects.filter(post_id=self.id).count()

        return context
```

This is the offending line of code:

`context['comment_count'] = Comments.objects.filter(post_id=self.id).count()`

If I manually replace `self.id` with a number, then it will correctly grab the comment count of the post.

Which brings me to my question:

How do I get the post.id if I am in a ListView?

edit:

```
from django.urls import path
from journal.views import PostListView, PostDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='post-list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
]
```

Comment: can show your urls code

Comment: @c.grey done, sorry about that

Comment: try to print self.id and see what its print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have posted your models. Assuming you have a ForeignKey from Comment to Post, and haven't specified a `related_name`, you can just do this in your template:

```
 {% for post in object_list %}
    {{ post.title }} # etc
    {{ post.comment_set.count }}
 {% endfor %}
```

If you did set a related_name, use that instead of `comment_set`.